# Maven dependencies not applying or am I doing something wrong?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

Hey I have created a Maven Project in IntelliJ and added some dependencies in my pom.xml for using external libraries. But I always have to import the classes in the class where I want to work with the classes of these libraries.

For example one dependency:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datavec</groupId>
            <artifactId>datavec-local</artifactId>
            <version>${dl4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

And I use this line of code in my class:

```
DataAnalysis analysis = AnalyzeLocal.analyze(schema, recordReader);
        HtmlAnalysis.createHtmlAnalysisFile(analysis, new File("X:/Churn_Modelling/analysis.html"));
```

I must import DataAnalysis.
I mean it would be ok if I would import the right class by clicking on import, but it is the wrong one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use imports in your Java source code. Maven dependencies do not replace imports.

They make imports possible, though. Without the dependency, the import will fail.

Answer (score 0):

If you can import the class then it means the dependency is successfully added to class path whether it is right or wrong.

Then the question is, is there only one DataAnalysis class in the class path. You can check by ctrl+space.

If it is the only one, then I think it is dependency problem. Your dependency version is dynamic,

> ${dl4j.version}

So in the build time may be it has different value. You can check it, IntelliJ maven tool Dependency part. In different dependency version, the class path would be changed.

If you are sure about, downloaded dependency with version is what you need, then it but the class is not what you expect, then try to restart the IntelliJ with clearing caches mode.

Hope one of these helps you.